# Java 8 Optional: choose between two possibly null values

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have to choose between two String variables - the first that has non `null` value.
If they are both `null` - then I want to exit the method.
This can be done in the following piece of code:

```
String value1 = <get from somewhere>
String value2 = <get from somewhere else>
String target = null;
if (value1 != null) target = value1;
else if (value2 != null) target = value2;
if (target == null) return null;
```

It can also be done in short form:

```
String target = value1 != null ? value1 : value2 != null ? value2 : null;
if (target == null) return null;
```

I am struggling with how to do this in fluent form with `Optional`
Note: I can only use Java 8 syntax (so no `Optional.or()`)

Comment: Your version using the ternary operator is not the same as the one using `if` blocks. In the first version, `value2` seems to take precedence over `value1` when neither is null.

Comment: Do a search in the duplicate link for `Optional`, the answer with some 30+ votes.

Comment: @ernest_k. you are right, corrected

Comment: `Stream.of(first, second).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst()` I guess...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, if my question is duplicate, why don't you close it as such?

Comment: I did close it...if the duplicate link doesn't fix your Java 8 need, then drop a comment and explain why, and someone may reopen your question.

Comment: @Eugene If you think so, you should absolutely vote to reopen and you don't need to ask my permission to do that :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String target = Optional.ofNullable(value1).orElse(value2)
```

If `value1 == null`, then return `value2` - which either has a value or is null. There is no need to explicitly handle the case of `value2 == null` by mapping it to null.

Answer (score 8):

If you have just two options, you could do it with:

```
target = Optional.ofNullable(value1)
            .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(value2).orElse(null));
```

Even if this can be made to work for more that two variables.

With java-9, this could be made a bit more readable:

```
target = Optional.ofNullable(value1)
            .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(value2))
            .orElse(null);
```

The other answer has a very good point, indeed; thus this can be further simplified to not use `Optional`s, at all, still a single line:

```
 target = value1 != null ? value1 : value2;
```

Comment: I think this is clearer than the `Stream.of` answer from another question.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher not really... especially if you would have three variables, this will get ugly very fast. But it's an option, I guess

Comment: yes. it is clear for two optionals. perhaps, for completeness, you can mention that Java 9 solved this with `Optional.or`

Comment: plus the answer posted here is not posted in the other question

Comment: @SharonBenAsher So he should post the answer on the other question.

Comment: @Eugene Fair enough. It's a still a clear duplicate that you shouldn't have re-opened. I don't want to get into a cycle of closing and re-opening it - so can you give a good reason why it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @Michael I have to re-read them when I have a bit more time and with a fresh mind, but this place is not one we should always agree on - you consider being a duplicate, please close it (again), untimely it will get deleted too, no offense whatsoever from me. thank you for the comments actually

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check AND condition

```
Optional.ofNullable(value)
                    .filter( res -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty((CharSequence) val.get()))
                    .ifPresent( finalResul -> {
                        //apply logic
                    });
```